# Replace string according dictionary file in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

```
cat input

aaa paul peter
bbb john mike
ccc paul mike 
bbb paul john
```

And my dictionary file dict:

```
cat dict

aaa OOO
bbb 111
ccc 222
```

I need to find string form `input` and if match first column in file `dict`, print second column form file `dict` to first column file `input`. I can use `sub` and `gsub`, but I have thousands row in `dict` file (with different letters).

```
cat output:

000 paul peter
111 john mike
222 paul mike 
111 paul john
```

Thank you for any help.

My solution:

```
  awk:

awk '{sub(/aaa/,"000",$1); sub(/bbb/,"111",$1); sub(/ccc/,"222",$1)1' input
```

UPDATE:

If not found match from `input` in `dict`, keep the word in first column unchanged.

cat input

```
aaa paul peter
bbb john mike
ccc paul mike 
bbb paul john
ddd paul peter

cat dict

aaa OOO
bbb 111
ccc 222

cat output:

000 paul peter
111 john mike
222 paul mike 
111 paul john
ddd paul peter
```

Comment: How does `input` have two entries for `bbb`, shouldn't it be unique?

Comment: No any entry in first column can repeat many times. Differences are in other columns.

Comment: @fedorqui I put my try. But this work if I have only substitution a few words. And I would like to read from dict file. I am not sure if I can use awk..

Comment: what should happen for rows in which there is no match against the dict file?

Comment: yeah this is very good point. Probably just keep value form input file (so it is stay unchanged).

Comment: @Geroge could you update your example data and associated output to reflect that? Also I think my answer needs an update considering this.

Comment: @Aaron Just updated.

Comment: @Geroge: Can you provide an example for your information in `UPDATE`? How the output should look like?

Comment: @Inian Added an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more generalized approach as suggested by [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) in comments for handling mismatch in the names in the `input` and `dict` files can be done something as,

```
awk 'FNR==NR {dict[$1]=$2; next} {$1=($1 in dict) ? dict[$1] : $1}1' dict input
```

---

My original solution below works on the cases when there is no missed mappings between the `input` and the `dict` files.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{hash[$2FS$3]=$1; next}{for (i in hash) if (match(hash[i],$1)){print $2, i} }' input dict
OOO paul peter
111 john mike
111 paul john
222 paul mike
```

The idea is to create a hash-map with index as `$2FS$3` and value as `$1`, i.e. `hash["paul peter"]="aaa"`, etc. Once this is constructed, now the dictionary file is looked upon to see matching lines from `$1` in `dict` with hash value from `input` file. If the match is found printing the contents as needed.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to this answer. Using fields 2 and 3 seems a bit unnecessary. Also, why going through the input first and then through the dict? The mapping is done through the dict, so it should be loaded first and then use its values to change the data in input.

Comment: @fedorqui: I happen to use this approach for the first requirement before the change, it so happens I didn't make it flexible for other cases. Can i use your comment as an update in my answer with due credit?

Comment: I see. Since it is not flexible and has more complexity than a simple `val in array` without any loop, I think it looks clear that parsing `dict` first must be the easiest way!

Comment: @fedorqui: exactly!

Comment: How would you modify the command to change column 2 instead? I have tried ````awk 'FNR==NR {dict[$1]=$2; next} {$2=($2 in dict) ? dict[$1] : $2}1' dict input```` (if column 2 in dict, replace) but it simply deletes column 2 from my file. I have a command with a for loop that works but it takes ages.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could effectively use GNU `join` :

```
sort input > sorted_input
sort dict > sorted_dict
join sorted_dict sorted_input -o 1.2,2.2,2.3
```

Which gives the following output with your example data (notice the sort modified the output, but is necessary for `join` to work) :

```
OOO paul peter
111 john mike
111 paul john
222 paul mike
```

All of this relies on the join field being the first of each file, otherwise you'll need to specify which field the files should be joined on.

The `-o` parameter is a format output specification and refers to the fields of each file we want in the output : the second field of the `dict`, followed by every field but the first of the `input`.

You've mentioned some keys might be not found in `dict` and you want to keep the value from the first field of `input`. There's a `-a` option to handle that, but it will mess with our output, so I think the easier is to do two executions, a first one which outputs lines with correspondances in each file and a second one which handles lines without correspondance in `dict` :

```
$ join sorted_dict sorted_input -o 1.2,2.2,2.3; join sorted_dict sorted_input -v 2
OOO paul peter
111 john mike
111 paul john
222 paul mike
ddd paul peter
```

If it adds too much of an overhead because of the size of the files, you should instead do a single execution with `-a 2`, without output specification, and then transform the result with `sed`, `awk` or something else to handle lines with the missing field.

Comment: Thank you. Does it works if I have different number of column - for example input have 500 rows and dict have 50K rows?

Comment: rows or columns? With rows, yes it'll work ; I guess it should be as efficient as any `awk` script you can write, but you should definitely test it. With too much columns, the `-o` format specification would be bothersome to write and I'd instead rely on `cut`'s ranges (e.g. `cut -d' ' -f2-` which will only remove the first field)

Comment: There's always a tool for your task in the GNU toolbox ! (granted it's often `awk` :p)

Answer (score 2):

Changed my answer to:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if ($1 in a)print a[$1],$2,$3; else print $0}' dict input
```

prints

```
OOO paul peter
111 john mike
222 paul mike
111 paul john
ddd paul peter
```

With the command NR==FNR the following command is only excecuted on on the first file. Each line is stored into the array a with the key $1 and the value $2. Then $1 in a takes $1 from the second file and looks if the value can be found in the array a. If it is true then then a[$1] prints the number and $2 and $3 the name. Now there is an additional else clause which keeps prints the whole line from input if no match is found.

Comment: You can probably say `{$1=($1 in a) ? dict[$1] : $1}1` to make it more concise.

Comment: @Inian I made it work with `awk 'FNR==NR {dict[$1]=$2; next} {$1=($1 in dict) ? dict[$1] : $1}1' dict input`, I think you are overcomplicating the indexes.

Comment: @fedorqui Thats a nice improvement. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

awk was waaay faster for the operation, but here is a pure bash solution.

```
#!/bin/bash

typeset -A dict

function add_dict()
{
   dict[$1]=$2
}

add_dict aaa 000
add_dict bbb 111
add_dict ccc 222

while read row
do
   column=(${row//:/ })
   if [ "${dict[${column[0]}]}" ];then
      echo ${dict[${column[0]}]} ${column[1]} ${column[2]}
   else
      echo ${column[0]} ${column[1]} ${column[2]}
   fi 
done < /tmp/1M.txt

#1 Million lines processed in
#real   0m40.173s
#user   0m37.668s
#sys    0m2.462s

#time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{if ($1 in a)print a[$1],$2,$3; else print $0}' dict 1M.txt > processed.txt

#real   0m0.281s
#user   0m0.242s
#sys    0m0.024s
```